# Airflow 2.0.0+ - Pass a Dynamically Generated Dictionary to DAG Triggered by TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: python, airflow

Previously, I was using the **python_callable** parameter of the **TriggerDagRunOperator** to **dynamically alter the dag_run_obj payload that is passed to the newly triggered DAG**.

Since its removal in Airflow 2.0.0 (Pull Req: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6317), is there a way to do this, without creating a custom TriggerDagRunOperator?

For context, here is the flow of my code:

```
#Poll Amazon S3 bucket for new received files
fileSensor_tsk = S3KeySensor()

#Use chooseDAGBasedOnInput function to create dag_run object (previously python_callable was used directly in TriggerDagRunOperator to create the dag_run object for the new triggered DAG)
#dag_run object will pass received file name details to new DAG for reference in order to complete its own work
chooseDAGTrigger_tsk = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='chooseDAGTrigger_tsk',
    python_callable=chooseDAGBasedOnInput,
    provide_context=True
)

triggerNewDAG_tsk = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='triggerNewDAG_tsk',
    trigger_dag_id='1000_NEW_LOAD'
)

triggerNewDAG2_tsk = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='triggerNew2DAG_tsk',
    trigger_dag_id='1000_NEW2_LOAD'
) ...
```

Any help or commentary would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** - adding previously used python_callable function used in TriggerDagRunOperator:

```
def intakeFile(context, dag_run_obj):

    #read from S3, get filename and pass to triggered DAG
    bucket_name = os.environ.get('bucket_name')
    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws_default')
    s3_hook.copy_object()
    s3_hook.delete_objects()
    ...

    dag_run_obj.payload = {
        'filePath': workingPath,
        'source': source,
        'fileName': fileName
    }

    return dag_run_obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/triggerdagrunoperator) now takes a `conf` parameter to which a dictinoary can be provided as the conf object for the DagRun.  [Here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#passing-parameters-when-triggering-dags) is more information on triggering DAGs which you may find helpful as well.

**EDIT**

Since you need to execute a function to determine which DAG to trigger and *do not* want to create a custom `TriggerDagRunOperator`, you could execute `intakeFile()` in a `PythonOperator` (or use the `@task` decorator with the [Task Flow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html)) and use the return value as the `conf` argument in the `TriggerDagRunOperator`.  As part of Airflow 2.0, return values are automatically pushed to XCom within many operators; the `PythonOperator` included.

Here is the general idea:

```py
def intakeFile(*args, **kwargs):

    # read from S3, get filename and pass to triggered DAG
    bucket_name = os.environ.get("bucket_name")
    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id="aws_default")
    s3_hook.copy_object()
    s3_hook.delete_objects()
    ...

    dag_run_obj.payload = {
        "filePath": workingPath,
        "source": source,
        "fileName": fileName,
    }

    return dag_run_obj


get_dag_to_trigger = PythonOperator(
    task_id="get_dag_to_trigger",
    python_callable=intakeFile
)

triggerNewDAG_tsk = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="triggerNewDAG_tsk",
    trigger_dag_id="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_dag_to_trigger', key='return_value') }}",
)

get_dag_to_trigger >> triggerNewDAG_tsk
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The issue with the conf parameter is that I need to be able to dynamically read a file that was delivered to my S3 bucket, to know which exact DAG to trigger using TriggerDagRunOperator. In earlier versions, I am using the python_callable parameter to call a function that updated  and returned the dag_run_obj.payload dictionary to TriggerDagRunOperator (at run-time).

Comment: For reference, I have edited the post to include the python function called by the depreciated python_callable parameter in TriggerDagRunOperator. Thank you.

Comment: @mathee I updated the answer following your question update.  Thanks for the additional context!

Comment: Thank you! A combination of both your responses helped me resolve this issue! I was able to set up the conf parameter properly using the xcom variable. I was able to use the conf setup in my new DAG after.