# Airflow 1.x TriggerDagRunOperator pass {{ds}} as conf

Tags: jinja2, airflow

In Airflow 1.x (not 2.x), I want DAG1 to trigger DAG2.
and want to pass DAG1's templated date {{ds}} as a 'conf' dict parameter like {"day":"{{ds}}"} to DAG2, so that DAG2 can access it via {{dag_run.conf['day']}}

But DAG1 just ends up passing the literal string '{{ds}}' instead of '2021-12-03'

DAG2 uses an SSHOperator, not PythonOperator (for which a solution seems to [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66496541/4450157))

DAG 1:

```
from airflow.operators import TriggerDagRunOperator

def fn_day(context, dagrun_order):
    dagrun_order.payload = {"day": "{{ds}}"}
    return dagrun_order

trig = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        trigger_dag_id="ssh",
        task_id='trig',
        python_callable=fn_day,
        dag=dag)
```

DAG 2 :

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator

ssh = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='ssh_vm',
    task_id='echo',
    command="echo {{dag_run.conf['day']}}"
)
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68381759/10569220) , I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: @NicoE, i'm using airflow 1.*